# Java process is not killed after stopping Debug in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Java project which uses Gradle to build. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Community Edition). When I click on debug, it creates a Java process. But it doesnt kill this process when I click on stop. So, everytime I click on debug, the Java processes keep accumulating. Also, in the activity monitor a new no name process shows up every time with parent process as IntelliJ idea. Also, in the dock/taskbar, the Java processes accumulate.

Before debug -

```
% ps -fea | grep java
  503   509 97339   0  7:07PM ttys002    0:00.00 grep java
%
```

After 2 debug and stop cycle (This can go more. Just 2 for example) -

```
% ps -fea | grep java
  503 90731 82751   0  5:18PM ??         0:27.31 /Users/name/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-15.0.5/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=127.0.0.1:61543 --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/akashravi.vasishta/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-workday-1-bin/5xnutbozhlaeef1xb3yswps8s/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-launcher-6.9.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.9
  503 90802 82751   0  5:24PM ??         0:18.60 /Users/name/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/azul-15.0.5/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=127.0.0.1:61580 --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /Users/akashravi.vasishta/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-workday-1-bin/5xnutbozhlaeef1xb3yswps8s/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-launcher-6.9.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.9
%
```

I have to kill these 2 process manually. First of, are these 2 processes the JVM processes ? If not, what are they ? In my code I am also creating a Jetty server, is it that ? Even if it is the Jetty server shouldnt it be killed when I stop debug ? How to kill these Java process when I stop debug ?

P.S. The activity monitor image and $ps output differ because screenshot was taken at a different time.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try enabling `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Kill the debug process immediately`. If the problem remains report the problem at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA or https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Tried the "Kill the debug process immediately". Didnt work. But I tried debug mode on Eclipse for the same project and when stopped, everything stops and there is no Java process left behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following below command to kill all your java processes as,

`sudo kill $(ps aux | grep -i java | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: This will do the job, but I dont want another manual solution. I want it to happen automatically or via code, maybe gradle ? or maybe intelliJ ?

Comment: Maybe then you can write a custom shell script and then run this command after all your executions had been done in your build gradle file!
Also, please mark this as a correct answer if this helps you out.